# Edittext with Shape-Background have "lines" around Border

Tags: android, android-edittext, shapes

i use a Edittext with a rounded Shape as Background. The Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp" >

<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@color/color_main_black"/>

<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

<solid android:color="#c8000000"/>
</shape>
```

So far so good. On "normal"-State it looks fine, but if the Editfield have Focus, so the Shape looks like it "redraws" everytime.
There are Lines around the Border, which are getting darker and darker.

The following Image shows the Normal-State, and below them the Focus-State with the Problem (after a few Seconds):
[Show the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvC9H.jpg)

I've enlarged the picture, so you can see, what is the Problem.
I don't know, where the Problem is, so hope that anyone could help me, thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've just tested the following Code

```
GradientDrawable retGD = new GradientDrawable();

retGD.setColor(colorBackground);
retGD.setCornerRadii(finalCornorRadius);
retGD.setStroke(strokeWidth, colorStroke);
```

but it still the same Result.
Please, can anyone test it? I don't know where the Problem is!

Comment: Have you given background from java file?? if yes then please post of that too.

Comment: Hi, i set the Background-Drawable in xml like the following: `<EditText
...
        android:background="@drawable/draw_element_background_dark"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_main_white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/color_main_gray"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />`

Comment: Nobody an Idea?